# Remove Character $ from Decimal Calculation

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to sum up a column that has values, but they have the character "$" in front of the value.

How would I remove the $ in front of the value to convert it into a decimal so I do not get any errors?

Here is the code I am using to do this:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.DataItem != null)
    {
        // Set the capacity label text

        sum += Decimal.Parse(e.Row.Cells[4].Text);

        Label5.Text = "Total:"+" $" + sum.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `NumberStyles.Currency`

```
sum += Decimal.Parse(e.Row.Cells[4].Text, NumberStyles.Currency);
```

This instructs the parser to allow the "$" character. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)